# Using a keyword search field with category selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a search page where a user can input a keyword and return a set of results, plus have the option of filtering by category if need be. I can get both of my fields (input and radios) working independently yet not combined. So if someone does a keyword search then those results show. If someone does a filer by category, then those results show. Though I'm not sure how to use my search box after a category is selected. I'd like my search box to search within the category results.

HTML

```html
    <div id="app" v-cloak>  
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row search-wrapper"> 
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Filter by keyword"  v-model="search">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <button type="submit">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>  
                    </span>
                </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 text-right">
      <div data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-all">
        <input type="radio" v-model="selectedCategory" value="All" /> All
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-hr">
        <input type="radio" v-model="selectedCategory" value="HR" /> Our People
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-finance">
        <input type="radio" v-model="selectedCategory" value="Finance" /> Finance
      </label>
     <label class="btn btn-sm btn-other">
        <input type="radio" v-model="selectedCategory" value="Other" /> Other
      </label>
</div>
    </div>    
  </div> <!-- search wrapper -->
  <div class="row sm-padding">
    <div v-for="form in filteredForms" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 sm-padding">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="form-type" v-bind:class="{ compClass }"></div>
        <div  class="text-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></div> 
        <div class="box__title"> {{ form.name }} </div>
        <div class="box__subtitle"> {{ form.category }} </div>
        <div class="box__link"> <a href="#" title="">Use this form</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="filteredForms.length === 0" >
      <div class="box box__empty"> No Match Found</div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- results --> 
 </div> <!-- container -->
</div> <!-- #app -->
```

Vue JS

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      forms: [
        { name: 'Learning and Professional Development Record', category: 'HR', activeColor: 'red', views: 312},
        { name: 'New Vendor Request', category: 'Finance', activeColor: 'blue', views: 23121 },
        { name: 'On-call allowance', category: 'HR', activeColor: 'red', views: 231},
        { name: 'Overtime Claim', category: 'HR', activeColor: 'red', views: 443},
        { name: 'Alteration of Kindergarten Enrolment', category: 'Other', activeColor: 'yellow', views: 403},
        { name: 'Adjustment to vendor details', category: 'Finance', activeColor: 'blue', views: 8843}
      ],
      selectedCategory: 'All',
      search: '',
  },
  computed: {
    filteredForms: function() {
        var vm = this;
        var category = vm.selectedCategory;

       var forms = vm.forms.filter((form) => {
       return form.name.toLowerCase().includes(vm.search.toLowerCase());
          });

      if(category === "All") {
            return forms;
        } else {
          return vm.forms.filter(function(dept) {
          return dept.category === category;
            });
    }
    }
  }
})
```

Pen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/trixeldigital/pen/qpQmrG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter on a given category works on the whole list, not the list filtered by keyword:

```js
filteredForms: function() {
    var vm = this;
    var category = vm.selectedCategory;

    var forms = vm.forms.filter((form) => {
        return form.name.toLowerCase().includes(vm.search.toLowerCase());
    });

    if(category === "All") {
        return forms;
    } else {
        // return vm.forms.filter(function(dept) {
        // replace with
        return forms.filter(function(dept) {
            return dept.category === category;
        });
    }
}
```

Here's an updated Pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpQzpz

Comment: I see what I did there. So close to where I was, thanks for this. Now just have to work out how to pass the colors to my styles.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your computed value. 
Your forms array is now filtered by only one array iteration.

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      forms: [
        { name: 'Learning and Professional Development Record', category: 'HR', activeColor: 'red', views: 312},
        { name: 'New Vendor Request', category: 'Finance', activeColor: 'blue', views: 23121 },
        { name: 'On-call allowance', category: 'HR', activeColor: 'red', views: 231},
        { name: 'Overtime Claim', category: 'HR', activeColor: 'red', views: 443},
        { name: 'Alteration of Kindergarten Enrolment', category: 'Other', activeColor: 'yellow', views: 403},
        { name: 'Adjustment to vendor details', category: 'Finance', activeColor: 'blue', views: 8843}
      ],
      selectedCategory: 'All',
      search: '',
  },
  computed: {
    filteredForms() {
      return this.forms.filter(dept => (dept.category === this.selectedCategory || this.selectedCategory === 'All') && dept.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This solution works a charm. I'm only just learning Vue and haven't come across using pipes to separate statements yet. Thanks heaps for this.